# Django 2.1 urls returning error

Tags: python, django, url

> please i need help, no matter how much i try, my site keep returning a
>   404 error due to fault in urls setup

*my views*

```
 from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from catalog.models import Category, Product
from django.template import RequestContext
from untitled13.cart import cart
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from untitled13.catalog.forms import ProductAddToCartForm


def index(request, template_name='catalog/index.html'):
    page_title = 'online shop for all items'
    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def show_category(request, category_slug, template_name='catalog/category.html'):
    c = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
    products = c.product_set.all()
    page_title = c.name
    meta_keywords = c.meta_keywords
    meta_description = c.meta_description
    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def show_product(request, product_slug, template_name='catalog/product.html'):
    p = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=product_slug)
    categories = p.categories.filter(is_active=True)
    page_title = p.name
    meta_keywords = p.meta_keywords
    meta_description = p.meta_description
    if request.method == 'POST':
        postdata = request.POST.copy()
        form = ProductAddToCartForm(request, postdata)
        if form.is_valid():
            cart.add_to_cart()
            if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
                request.session.delete_test_cookie()
            url = 'show_cart'
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        form = ProductAddToCartForm(request=request, label_suffix=':')
        form.fields['product_slug'].widget.attrs['value'] = product_slug
        request.session.set_test_cookie()
    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

*my urls*

```
"""untitled13 URL Configuration
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('catalog/', include('catalog.urls')),
    path('static/', static.serve),
    path('cart/', include('cart.urls')),
]
```

*my cart view*

```
    from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from untitled13.cart import cart


def show_cart(request, template_name="cart/cart.html"):
    cart_item_count = cart.get_cart_items(request)
    page_title = 'Shopping Cart'
    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(),
                              context_instanc=RequestContext(request))
```

*the error page*

Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/site

Using the URLconf defined in untitled13.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
admin/
catalog/
static/
cart/
```

The current path, site, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `path('site/', views.index)` to your urlpatterns if you want '/site' to link to your index view. The error it gives you is really straight forward.

You would also need to import the views.py file containing the index view.
`from your_app import views`

Comment: It returns same error even when I use the address http://127.0.0.1:8000 or http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog

Comment: You haven't defined a root URL [e.g path('/$', views.index)] so that will 404. You haven't shown us the contents of the urls.py in your catalog app or module in your question. You should get an error if catalog.urls (a file in catalog/urls.py) doesn't exist, I think.  Improve your question by showing what the error says in responding to the 127.0.0.1:8000/catalog request and adding your 'catalog.urls' please